# I want to ask you about the structure of "query, key, value" of "transformer"

Tags: nlp, pytorch, translation, transformer-model, self-attention

I'm a beginner at NLP.
So I'm trying to reproduce the most basic transformer all you need code.

But I got a question while doing it.

In the MultiHeadAttention layer,
I printed out the shape of "query, key, value".
However, the different shapes of "query" and "key, value" were printed.
"self-attention" eventually finds a correlation with oneself, which is different".I don't understand the shape of "query, key, value".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S97ln.png)
The value of "query, key, value" comes from src, but why are the values different?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQaTR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b38AG.png)

I brought the code from here.

https://github.com/ndb796/Deep-Learning-Paper-Review-and-Practice/blob/master/code_practices/Attention_is_All_You_Need_Tutorial_(German_English).ipynb

Comment: I highly recommend everyone to read this blog for details of the transformer if you haven't. https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/

Comment: somebody help me